# Problems installing sql management studio express on win7-64

Tags: sql-server, windows-7-x64

Here's what happened:

1. install sql express 2008
2. install sql 2008 sp1
3. download and install SSMSE x64. There is a popup re incompatibility with the OS, and the help takes you back to the sp1 download page. It won't install... in fact the install that comes up appears to be for sql server express and I see no mention of SSMSE anywhere in the tangle of dialogs. 
   There appears to be no version of SSMSE for Win7-64 at this time. Do you know any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

What a joke. It's a crapped out installer. You have to choose to install a new instance of sql express... but it actually installs SSMSE instead. Probably a new low in installer design.